# Archive page doesn't work

Tags: theme-development, archives

I'm trying to build my first custom theme by watching some tutorials and tips.

So I have the index, custom pages, and I tried to make the "archive" page and it redirects to my index. The file "archive.php" is there, and in the Reading Settings I requested that the "Blog" page (created in the Pages menu) receive the posts.

How to proceed?

[image]
[image]

**archive.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="content">
    Testing 123
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a static page as your front page (as shown in your first image), then neither archive.php or home.php will work. The page hierarchy for static home pages is:

1. Page Template
2. page-{slug}.php
3. page-{id}.php
4. page.php
5. index.php

If you want to show an archive on your front page, select 'your latest posts', then home.php will work.

In either case, front-page.php will be the first in the hierarchy.

Comment: Hey @Nathan Johnson, thanks. But i dont want to show my archive in my front page. I want to show the archive when access the "localhost/blog".

Answer (score 0):

You should use home.php file instead of index.php, this is the [Wp template hierarchy structure](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

UPDATE:

Your archive file should be like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="<?php post_class(); ?>">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="post-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
    </article>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I've tried to rename my index to "home.php", but, nothing happens.

Comment: You don't have to rename it, you should have most of those files in your theme folder, if you are developing your own theme you should create them. single.php, page.php, home.php, front-page.php, archive.php and so on you can also create archive-custom-post-type.php if you have custom post types.

Comment: your archive should aldo be like this:

Comment: thank you. My archive file is almost exactly as you showed it. My dir structure: http://i.imgur.com/7TvxQUe.png

` <?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="container">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <div class="post-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">More!</a>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>`

Comment: I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong. Is my file structure/settings incorrect?

Comment: You should have that loop into a page template, and then use that page template in your desired page.